# too many public methods with @ModelAttribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, refactoring, public-method

I have a controller that is 1600 lines long. This is mostly populated with a bunch of public methods with the `@ModelAttribute` annotation.  It also has a few `@RequestMapping` methods.

I would like to bring down the line count and break-up this class. How do you handle multiple public methods with `@ModelAttribute` annotation?  Aren't they all invoked whenever a request is processed?

Answer (score 2):

> I have a controller that is 1600 lines long

Gulp.

> How do you handle multiple public methods with `@ModelAttribute` annotation? Aren't they all invoked whenever a request is processed?

When used to annotate a method, this annotation indicates that the method's return value should be used to populate the model for every request executed by that controller class, regardless of which `@RequestMapping` method is executed.

My suggestion is that you perform an audit to see which views (e.g. JSPs) use which model data provided by the various `@ModelAttribute` methods. It's likely that each view only uses a subset of that data.

Once you've figured out which combinations of `@ModelAttribute` and `@RequestMapping` methods go together, then break those up into individual classes.

If that doesn't fly (maybe all of the views really do use all of the data), then consider extracting the `@ModelAttribute` methods out of the class altogether, and stitch them together using a single method which amalgamates their outputs together manually (e.g. pass the `Model` or `ModelMap` object from the `@RequestMapping` method to this new method, which then adds the bits of model to that object.

Remember, `@ModelAttribute`-annotated methods are just a convenient way to add extra model data. They're not the only way.

Comment: Thank you.  I shall try this in our code and post the results.  I needed a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

@ModelAttribute methods can also return void:

```
@ModelAttribute
public void populateModel(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("key", "value");
    // keep adding any number of attributes...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you group multiple `@ModelAttribute`s together? For example, if you have three methods one each for retrieving the values of three different select boxes, you could perhaps put them all into one method.